# MVC 4 link_to helper (similar to rails)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, asp.net-mvc-4

In Ruby on Rails you can do this:

```
link_to("My link text", someModelInstance)
```

This will generate a link with the caption "My link text" and a href that points to the item stored in the `someModelInstance` variable.

Is there a similar way to do this is MVC 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use T4MVC to achieve this in MVC.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I need. If anyone else want to get started with T4MVC, have a look at http://blog.rajsoftware.com/post/2011/04/24/Getting-Started-with-T4MVC.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is something called Actionlink which creates a hyperlink which intern points to particular controller & action

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkName", "ControllerName", "ActionName")
```

This will generate

```
<a href="/ControllerName/ActionName">LinkName</a>
```

Comment: Was aware of this, but it is not exactly what I need. I need an easy and non-volitile way of redirecting to a Details-page of an element. T4MVC seems to work well for this. (by doing: @Html.ActionLink("detalis", MVC.MyModelName.Details(item.ID))   )